# biblatex: How to manage "p." and "pp." marks in footnotes and in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm making the first steps in Xelatex. Now I'm trying to make my bachelor in this program.

I have TexLive 2010 (with updates 22.02.2011) installed on Kubuntu 10.04 . 
My text includes five languages (French, English, German, Greek (modern and ancient) Russian and Polish). The main language is French.

The file that I've made is compiling well enough except two problems:

1. In footnotes and in the bibliography after compilation the period of pages is always has "p." even if pages in .bib file is done like `pages = {2--8}` (`@Book`, `@Article`, `@Misc`, `@Booklet`  etc). How to make it shown like "pp."?
   I've read the manual and tried `\nop` and `\nopp` - it doesn't help.
2. How to make the small caps in footnotes and in the bibliography for the surnames of authors in Greek and Russian? (With the surnames in latin alphabet everything is ok.)

Here is my file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{unifrmr}%%This is the package for the title page and the geometry of the body of the text

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress]{biblatex}

\bibliography{master}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing
\input{introduction.tex}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the text I use the `\footcite`, `\autocite` and `\cite` tags.

Would you help me, please? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to have any greeting. A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user3763".

Comment: I hope it's okay to slash on a little extension of the original question: I often want to cite with pp.78, denoting page 78 and following. Is there a way to do that directly in a way of \cite[78]{title}?

Comment: Does fontspec support small-caps in non-Latin script? It doesn't complain when there are Greek letters in a `\textsc`, but it only shows lowercase letters. I think this is a completely separate question from the first one. It is preferred to have only one question per post, so I think you should open a second question (“How to get non-Latin smallcaps?”).

Comment: @Owe: You should also add a separate question for this, as it is really a different issue (filokalos' question is about text in the bibliography listing, yours is about using `\cite`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The single "p." for page ranges is actually part of the biblatex definitions for the French language in `french.lbx`. To override this, add the following to your document preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  pages = {pp\adddot},
}
```

I can't really comment on your second question -- it may have nothing to do with biblatex, and I'm not versed in XeLaTeX. Just a thought: Do the fonts you use for the greek and russian alphabets actually feature small caps?

Comment: Thank you Very Much. It works. lockstep, you really saved my life. :)