# Biblatex, French and pp.

Tags: biblatex, french

I'm having a little problem with the settings of my bibliography. I think everyone is familiar with the difference between the number of pages, shortened "pp.", and the page referenced, shortened "p.".

Well, for some reasons, articles referenced in footnote (with `\autocite`) will properly write "pp." and "p." but other categories like "book" and "conference" won't. They display "p." for both fields.

I checked the `french.lbx` file of biblatex and it does say something like `pages = {pp\adddot}`. I tried overriding it with:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
pages = {pp\adddot},
}
```

in the preamble of my document but to no avail.

Any idea?

PS: I'm using:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,backref=false,hyperref=false,
     citestyle=verbose-note,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Make a small complete example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{pages = {pp\adddot}}` (with or without that comma in your example) worked for me...

Comment: Wasn't that [already answered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11775/biblatex-how-to-manage-p-and-pp-marks-in-footnotes-and-in-the-bibliography) by lockstep?

Answer (score 5):

Since `french.lbx` doesn't include `pp\adddot` anywhere, I suspect that the "pp." observed by you was caused by a bibliography entry featuring a hyphenation field with, say, `english`. And as henrique has stated, `\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{pages = {pp\adddot}}` works indeed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage[babel=other]{biblatex}

% \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{pages = {pp\adddot}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  hyphenation = {french},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pagetotal = {999},
}
@book{B02,
  hyphenation = {english},
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  pagetotal = {888},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```